# Definir papeis para usuários armazenados em Banco

Tags: mysql, sql, modelo-relacional

Como estruturar no banco de dados uma estrutura de papéis de usuários (usuários comum, empresário, site_amdin), cada usuário terá funcionalidades, poderes diferentes na aplicação que usará este banco de dados.

Tabela de usuários:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    created DATETIME,
    modified DATETIME
);
```

**OBS:** Banco MySQL. *Ela esta seguindo convenções do de nomenclatura do CakePHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu faria isso duma forma bem simples com uma tabela de tipos de utilizador:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    user_type_id INT,
    created DATETIME,
    modified DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE user_type (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    created DATETIME,
    modified DATETIME
);
```

Comment: Excelente ideia +1

Answer (score 2):

Eu seguiria a mesma lógica do Jorge, porém com um complemento:

Faria com permissão de módulos

```
CREATE TABLE modulos (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    modulo VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE user_permissao (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    id_user INT,    
    id_modulo INT,
    permissao VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
);
```

Comment: Excelente ideia Ronaldo +1

Comment: Ronaldo então teria esta duas tabelas além da de usuário?

Comment: Sim. Seria essas 4 tabelas

Comment: e a resposta do Jorge (tabela user_type) ? você não vê?

Comment: Excelente ideia +1